# Publish a web service on localhost in java eclipse

Tags: java, web-services

can any one tell me what are the steps to publish a web service in java using eclipse on localhost tomcat?

Comment: I have a web service already dveloped and tested now i just wann host that on local tomcat server ... can any one tell me the steps how can i do that so that it is availabel on network for my friend ...

Comment: yaa Created one war file of the project and deplooyed on tomcat after that?? this project contains the Web Service Wsdl file.... how to proceed after that...

Answer (score 0):

[Check this](http://www.roseindia.net/webservices/buildingsimplewebservice.shtml)

Edit:  as per your comment: you need to build the project and deploy the war on to tomcat.

to deploy put the war in webapps dir of TOMCAT

Comment: ok then try to access your wsdl using your web browser if you get wsdl once then it has been published , now you can access it from your remote client, if no security constraint added

Comment: I m getting the wsdl when i m using both localhost and machine name in url .... but when i use url with my machine name to create a cleint it gives error saying ""Selection must be WSDL"" what is this??

Comment: What URL exactly you are trying to access ? is your machine name is resolvable ?